# How can I use NavigationController and PageTabBarController at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I'm sorry to bother you and I really love Material Project, I hope I could use it skillfully and make a prettier app. I wonder if I could know **how can I use NavigationController and PageTabBarController at the same time**, since if I want to use one of them, I have to set it in the AppDelegate as the rootViewController, then what should I do to the other one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad you are enjoying Material :)

Take a look at this article [Application Architecture with Material](http://www.cosmicmind.com/danieldahan/application-architecture-with-material).

Basically, you can set the `PageTabBarController` as the `rootViewController` of the `NavigationController`, like this:

```
import UIKit
import Material

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let pageTabBarController = AppPageTabBarController(viewControllers: [RedViewController(), GreenViewController(), BlueViewController()], selectedIndex: 0)

        window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = AppNavigationController(rootViewController: pageTabBarController)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

That should do it. All the best.

Comment: I have tried it, but how could I modify NavigationController? I can't even edit its title now 

Comment: You only need to add the title by changing the navigationItem in whichever view is the rootViewController. So in this case, it would be accessed in the PageTabBarController itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, select the view, then Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller